# Project Euler 22, off by 18,609

Tags: python

I'm working on problem 22 of Project Euler:

Using `names.txt` (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.

For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth `3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53`, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53             = 49714.

What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

My code (below) gets the answer `871179673`. The correct answer should be `871198282`, which makes me off by about 18k.

```
def score(name, pos):
    score = 0

    for letter in name:
        if letter == "A": score += 1
        elif letter == "B": score += 2
        elif letter == "C": score += 3
        elif letter == "D": score += 4
        elif letter == "E": score += 5
        elif letter == "F": score += 6
        elif letter == "G": score += 7
        elif letter == "H": score += 8
        elif letter == "I": score += 9
        elif letter == "J": score += 10
        elif letter == "K": score += 11
        elif letter == "L": score += 12
        elif letter == "M": score += 13
        elif letter == "N": score += 14
        elif letter == "O": score += 15
        elif letter == "P": score += 16
        elif letter == "Q": score += 17
        elif letter == "R": score += 18
        elif letter == "S": score += 19
        elif letter == "T": score += 20
        elif letter == "U": score += 21
        elif letter == "V": score += 22
        elif letter == "W": score += 23
        elif letter == "X": score += 24
        elif letter == "Y": score += 25
        elif letter == "Z": score += 26
        else: score += 0
    # end for loop.

    return score * pos
#end def score.

f = open('names.txt')
string = f.readlines()
f.close()

names = sorted(str(string).split(","))
tscore = 0
pos = 1

for name in names:
    tscore += score(name, pos)
    pos += 1
#end for loop.

print tscore
```

If I run the 'Colin' example through my score function, I get the right result. I've tested a few other names from the list, and they score correctly as well. I googled the question and got various solutions, but since I'm new to python I'd like to learn what I did wrong. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Whoa! there, that's too many `if-elif`'s

Comment: Hint: take a look at the [`ord()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) to turn an ASCII character into a integer number..

Comment: `ord(char)-64` will do the exact same thing as those ifs.

Comment: Is "position in file" supposed to index from `0` or from `1`? And do any names have hyphens or spaces or apostrophes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
names = sorted(str(string).split(","))
```

to:

```
names = sorted(string[0].split(','))
```

File contains just one line, so you need to access that line using `string[0]`.  `file.readlines` returns a list containing all lines from the file, it's better to do something like:

```
names = f.read().split(',')
names.sort()
```

A shorter version of your program:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
def score(word):
    return sum(ascii_uppercase.index(c) + 1 for c in word.strip('"'))

with open('names.txt') as f:
  names = f.read().split(',')
  names.sort()
print sum(i*score(x) for i, x in enumerate(names, 1))
```

<sub>**Note:** `string` is a built-in module, don't use it as a variable name</sub>

Comment: Whoa! That worked, awesome! Why does that make a difference? Since the file is one line, wouldn't 'string' contain just the one line?

Comment: @Brian It does, but `string` is a list that contains that single line, to access that line in that list you need to do: `string[0]`(As `file.readlines` returns a list)

Comment: To be specific, by calling `str` on the `list` that `readlines()` returned, Brian introduced `[` and `]` into the names MARY and ALONSO.  That pushed `MARY` to the end of the list, because `[` sorted after `"`.  Simply `print names` to see that `'[\'"MARY"'` is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
with open("names.txt",'r') as f:
     d=f.read()
d=d.replace('"','')
#print(d)
names=d.split(',')
#print(names)
names.sort()
print(names)
gro=dict()
result=string.ascii_uppercase
count=1
for i in result:
   gro[i]=count
    count+=1
#print(gro)
sum=0
for ind,value in enumerate(names):
    #print(ind,value)
     temp=0
    for x in value:
       temp+=gro[x]
       print(temp)
    sum+=temp*(ind+1)
```

print(sum)

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

my way:

```
splitted = open('names.txt').read().replace('","',',').replace('"','').split(',')
```

description:
open the file, then read it, after that remove double qoutes by repalce them with none and at the end split the whole string by comma (,)
good luck